# How to call a function inside another function in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, function, stored-procedures

Here is my function called `funcone5` from where I am trying to call another function called `SPLIT_STR`. But I don't know where I am going wrong. After a long search over the net, I could not find the desired solution, so please help me out.

Here is my first function:

```
CREATE
    DEFINER = `root`@`192.168.0%`
    FUNCTION `funcone5`(say_code varchar(16), counter int, subject varchar(255)) 
    RETURNS text CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
    SET @my_counter = 0;
    SET @Values = "";
    SET @cussubject = "";
    SET @Query = CONCAT(
        "INSERT INTO tTimeTable (Section_Academic_Year_Code, Week_Day, PeriodNum, Subject_Code) VALUES"
    );

    vals_loop: LOOP
        SET @my_counter = @my_counter + 1;
        SET @cussubject = (SELECT SPLIT_STR(subject, "|", @my_counter));
        IF @my_counter = 6 THEN
            LEAVE vals_loop;
        END IF;
        
        SET @Values = CONCAT(
                @Values,
                " (",
                say_code,
                ", ",
                @my_counter,
                ", ",
                counter,
                ", ",
                @cussubject,
                ")"
        );
    END LOOP vals_loop;
    
    SET @queries = CONCAT(@Query, @Values);
    RETURN @queries;
END
```

And my second function:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`192.168.0%`
FUNCTION `SPLIT_STR`(strtosplit VARCHAR(255), delim char(1), pos tinyint(2)
RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET latin1
RETURN REPLACE(
        SUBSTRING(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(strtosplit, delim, pos),
            LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(strtosplit, delim, pos -1)) + 1
        ),
       delim,
       ''
)
```

Comment: What's the error? Calling a function inside a function is usually no problem.

Comment: actually its making my tool hanged like mysql workbench,phpmyadmin, toad for mysql and not letting me to save the procedure.so i believe there is some issues because i am calling the function inside a loop.